# Unable to load Ubuntu Software

Tags: drivers, software-center, graphics-tablet

not really a new user, but definitely not a power user.

I recently got a linux compatible art tablet. problem is, I can't access the downloaded drive for it. it's like it's not even there.

and when I click on the software center, (it's just called Ubuntu software now), and while it shows that it;s booting, it's just not... doing anything.

Also, I did the updates install trick in my terminal, did a few other tricks lifted for here and still nothing. and it tells me that the download center is just not here.

it's gone.

Can someone help me fix this? I would rather not have to reinstall my entire OS.

(edit)

Ok, So I managed to instal the blue software shaped like a bag with a white circle with plenty of square dots inside. and I got GIMP.

but now, I can't install my Veikk A15 tablet despite having downloaded the driver that should work on linux.

also, when I downloaded it, it was marked with a red lock at the bottom right. managed to get that off (feel so proud.) but it still won't install.

I got the .deb one, and when I tried to install it vial terminal, I got this. sudo apt install vktablet-1.0.3-2-x86_6.deb
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

what does it mean?

Comment: I have no idea what you are describing. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What 'tricks' are you talking about? What is the 'download center'?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, open Terminal and do `lsb_release -d` edit this post with the output. If you can, do the `sudo apt update` and tell us what error messages you see there.

Comment: @karel we do not know current Ubuntu version yet, and the question you mark as duplicate will not be applicable for Ubuntu versions later than 20.04. You may, until we know the release, want to retract your close vote.